# Polymer - best way to implement a global value for data binding?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

What is the best way to implement a `GOBAL_URL` value in a polymer 1.0  for all elements? Like in Angular 1 you have a constant service.

```
  <form is="iron-form"
    id="search"
    method="get"
    with-credentials="true"
    action="{{GOBAL_URL}}/api/v1/food_search"
    content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with using `iron-meta` element to share env variables ->[link](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-meta)

You can then use `iron-meta-query` to get global variable. You can even store object in there.

```
<iron-meta id="fanPages" key="fanPages" value=
        '{
          "fb": "https://facebook.com/your-site",
          "tw": "https://twitter.com/your-site",
          "inst":"https://www.instagram.com/your-site"
        }'>
```

Then in any other component you can get this variable by query it

```
<iron-meta-query id="query" key="fanPages" value="{{fanPages}}"></iron-meta-query>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a server URL, I use `localStorage` (or the [`<app-localstorage-document>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-storage) element). It would look something like:

```
<app-localstorage-document key="serverUrl" data="{{_serverUrl}}"></app-localstorage-document>
<iron-ajax url="[[_serverUrl]]/api/v1/food_search"></iron-ajax>
```

The `_serverUrl` property is initialized to a default URL.